# Retrieving timestamp with time zone in Postgresql-simple

Tags: haskell

I am aware that this issue has been raised in the [past before](https://github.com/lpsmith/postgresql-simple/issues/69), and now marked as resolved.

I am using `postgresql-simple` package along with `Data.Time`. If I make a query to retrieve a single column of type `timestamptz`, I get pattern match error. Pseudo-code below:

```
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Time (UTCTime,LocalTime,ZonedTime)
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple as Pg
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToRow
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToField
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.Time
import qualified Data.Vector as V
...
--- in main this is the code
[Pg.Only (i::UTCTime)] <- Pg.query conn "select lastupdated from constraints where name=?" ( Only ("carrier"::T.Text))
...
```

I get this error at run-time when executing the query (Please note above :

```
*** Exception: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at ...)
```

If I change above to an invalid type like below:

```
[Pg.Only (i::T.Text)] <- Pg.query conn "select lastupdated from constraints where name=?" ( Only ("carrier"::T.Text))
```

I get exception about type which shows that the expected type is indeed `timestamptz`:

```
*** Exception: Incompatible {errSQLType = "timestamptz",...,
errSQLField = "lastupdated", errHaskellType = "Text", errMessage = "types incompatible"}
```

Also, this is how the above query result looks in `psql` console:

```
          lastupdated          
-------------------------------
 2016-04-13 00:08:33.789761+00
 2016-04-13 14:33:38.27739+00
(2 rows)
```

My understanding is that `Data.Time.UTCTime` or `Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.Time.UTCTimestamp` should map to `timestamptz` type of `PostgreSQL`. Apparently, that understanding is wrong if I am getting those errors above. Will appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(times :: [Pg.Only UTCTime]) <-
    Pg.query conn "select lastupdated from constraints where name=?" (Only ("carrier" :: T.Text))
```

Your pattern match was not only enforcing that there'd be a list of `Only UTCTime`s, but also that there'd be exactly one element in the list. As you have two records, `query` will return a list with two elements and the pattern match fails.